# Multiple simultaneous user access with same credentials on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication

I'm using Laravel 5.1.34 with sessions stored using the file driver and I'm experiencing some weird behaviours on my production server:

Quite randomly the logged user session expires and the user gets kicked out, even after a few seconds of activities.

It happens for instance with the admin user.

Could it be that using the same credentials from different browsers might invalidate the session for the latest user who logs in?

I've tried to find something about it on the internet but with no luck.

Comment: It can happen if multiple user share same session. and most important where's your session cache store? we were using redis where we were clearing cache on some action from admin panel and so that we were having the same issue you are facing currently

Comment: I'm using the file driver to store sessions. I'm going to update the question

Comment: Does your server have a load balancer or something else that manages the requests to different machines?

Comment: Nope, it has a really simple configuration with one machine only.